# window.location.replace not working

Tags: javascript, window.location

i have written a javascript function thats posts a form and redirect to home page . Im using window.location.replace to get to home page. but instead of replacing the url the function is appending the url in front of current url. Whats the problem?

```
    $('#submit_fourth').click(function () {

    // send data to server to save in table dbo.aspnet_Users  =================================================
    var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
    var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    $.post("/Account/Register", { FirstName: firstname, LastName: lastname, UserName: username, Password: password, ConfirmPassword: password, Email: email });
    //send information to server
    alert('Congratulations! Your account has been sucessfully created.');
    //get back to the login screen
    window.location.replace("dgsmart/Central/Login");
```

current url is 184.180.25.240/dgsmart/account/register after register button click it becomes  184.180.25.240/dgsmart/account/central/login
i want url lyk this  184.180.25.240/dgsmart/central/login

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a form onsubmit event to call some function, if so you have to prevent the default behavior by return false; (for example)

```
window.location.replace("absolute-address"); /*window.location.replace('http://example.com/#' + initialPage); */
return false; //prevent the default behavior of the submit event
```

Comment: Ok but replace() stumps me sometimes so i mentioned it. Waiting for the guy to upvote or accept the answer then I can remove the later part

Comment: its still appending the url instead of replacing it :|. i have tried both window.loaction and window.location.href still no successs

Answer (score -1):

You can also using this code to set your ideal url...

```
<script>
    location.href='RegisterNew.php';
</script>
```